# Maximal degree of a map between orientable surfaces

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces, branched-covers

Suppose that $M$ and $N$ are closed connected oriented surfaces. It is well-known that **if $f \colon M \to N$ has degree $d > 0$, then $\chi(M) \le d \cdot \chi(N)$.**

> What is an elementary proof of this?

I found references to some H.Kneser's articles (1928, 1929, 1930). However, I am not sure that these give a complete proof.  Also they are written in German with obsolete notation.  Is there a survey on maps of surface where I can find the proof in English?

[Michael Albanese](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2312535/257176) suggests that we use the Gromov norm.  This path seems complicated (to me).  Is it possible that the original proof (before Gromov) is more elementary?

For example, if $\chi(M) > \chi(N)$, then one can easily prove that $d$ is zero, using the quadratic form on $H^1(N ; \mathbb{Z})$. Can we use this approach, or something similar, to get a precise estimate on $d$ in general?

Comment: An improved version of Kneser’s result was proved by Allan Edmonds, and implies this result: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=541331

Comment: Just to highlight this: the original poster (Andrey Ryabichev) has now written a nice article - https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07813 - answering the question.  It also has pictures and an overview of the literature.  +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best, elementary, self-contained, and clarifying proof of Kneser's result, including the desired inequality, is due to Richard Skora. See

Skora, Richard, The degree of a map between surfaces, Math. Ann. 276(1987), no.3, 415–423.

He careful handles the cases when the surfaces are not necessarily orientable, using absolute degree. He also includes a self-contained, general version of my "pinch followed by branched covering" theorem mentioned above, correcting my misstatement in the non-orientable case.

Comment: I thought up more simple proof of the factorisation theorem which goes in one step without induction. Now I wrote it down https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07813 Also here I prove some properties of the geometric degree, the proofs of which in old articles that I found are based on the absolute degree and ferefore too complicated. I will be grateful for any comments on this text!

Answer (score 17):

I like the Gromov norm approach. Another approach uses the [Milnor-Wood inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milnor%E2%80%93Wood_inequality?wprov=sfti1) (here I am assuming $\chi(M), \chi(N) < 0$ and $M, N$ are connected WOLG).  A discrete faithful representation of $\pi_1(N)$ to $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ gives a flat circle bundle of euler number $-\chi(N)$. Pulling back to $M$ via $f$ multiplies the Euler number of the pulled back bundle by $d$. By the Milnor-Wood inequality,  $-d\chi(N) \leq -\chi(M)$.

As I indicated in a comment above, [Edmonds proved](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=541331) that any map between surfaces is homotopic to a composition of a pinch map and a branched cover, improving the results of Kneser that you refer to. One can see that a pinch map increases Euler characteristic (for negative Euler characteristic surfaces) and branched covers satisfy the inequality by the [Riemann-Hurwitz formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula?wprov=sfti1)

One could probably also give a proof using the interpretation of $\chi(M)$ as the self-intersection number of $\Delta(M)$ in $M\times M$. This can be interpreted in terms of cup product of the Poincaré dual, and one should be able to give a fairly elementary proof.

Comment: Ian, sorry, I just noticed that you mention Edmonds as well.

Answer (score 12):

Allan Edmonds shows that such a map decomposes as the composition of a pinch (i.e., pinching off handles) and a branched cover, which immediately gives what you need.

> Edmonds, Allan L.
> Deformation of maps to branched coverings in dimension two.
> Ann. of Math. (2) 110 (1979), no. 1, 113–125.

His work certainly relies on Kneser.  If there is any modern presentation of Kneser's work, it would be in a survey by Edmonds.